# getting characters, my chess game keeps coming up with invalid move

Tags: java, character, move, chess

I'm really sorry to be annoying but I'm kind of panicking and stressed over this. Please don't give hate as this post can be seen as a "please help debug" post but I'm desperate. I don't understand what I am doing wrong and I've spent so long trying to figure it out. It runs but just keeps giving the Illegal move message. I'd be REALLY grateful of any insights on this.

game...

```
public class Game {


    private static String WHITEPLAYS_MSG = "White plays. Enter move:";
    private static String BLACKPLAYS_MSG = "Black plays. Enter move:";
    private static String ILLEGALMOVE_MSG = "Illegal move!";
    private static String WHITEWINS_MSG = "White wins!";
    private static String BLACKWINS_MSG = "Black wins!";

    private Board gameBoard;


    // Minimal constructor. Expand as needed (kt54)
    public Game() {
        gameBoard = new Board();
    }

    // Build on this method to implement game logic.
    public void play() {

        Player player1 = new Player("white");           //player one plays white
        Player player2 = new Player("black");           //player two plays black
        Piece piece1 = new Piece();
        Piece piece2 = new Piece();

        EasyIn2 reader = new EasyIn2();

        gameBoard = new Board();     //initializes the board so dont need to do so in main

        boolean done = false;      //2 while loops within large while loop?

        while (!done) {                     //keeps looping when no one has won yet
            gameBoard.printBoard();

            System.out.println(WHITEPLAYS_MSG);


            String Player1Pos1 = reader.getString();         //gets user input ... move from... to....   temporary variables
            int x1From = Player1Pos1.charAt(0) - 'a';                           //to transform the letter      ASCII values
            int y1From = 8 - (Player1Pos1.charAt(1) - '1') - 1;                           // to transform the number

            String Player1Pos2 = reader.getString();
            int x1To = Player1Pos2.charAt(0) - 'a';                           //to transform the letter
            int y1To = 8 - (Player1Pos2.charAt(1) - '1') - 1;                           // to transform the number

            //passing the entire gameBoard instance, not just the array
            if (!gameBoard.canFindPiece(gameBoard.board, x1From, y1From)) {      //to check if the starting position is allowed
                System.out.println(ILLEGALMOVE_MSG);

                if (gameBoard.canMovePiece(gameBoard.board, x1From, y1From, x1To, y1To, piece1, player1)) {
                    gameBoard.movePiece(gameBoard.board, x1From, y1From, x1To, y1To, player1, piece1);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(ILLEGALMOVE_MSG);

                }
            }


            if (player1.getNumberPiecesCaptured() == gameBoard.getStartingPiecesEach()) {
                done = true;
                System.out.println(WHITEWINS_MSG);
                break;
            } else {
```

board....

```
public class Board {


    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 8;             //images for pieces to be displayed on board
    private static final char FREE = '.';
    private static final char WHITEROOK = '♖';
    private static final char BLACKROOK = '♜';
    private static final char WHITEBISHOP = '♗';
    private static final char BLACKBISHOP = '♝';


    public static int moveNumber=1;
    private int startingPiecesEach= 4 ;
    private int boardsize;
    public char[][] board;


    public Board() {
        this.boardsize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

        board = new char[boardsize][boardsize];

        // Clear all playable fields
        for (int x = 0; x < boardsize; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < boardsize; y++)
                board[x][y] = FREE;

        // Put a single bishop in the middle
        // Obviously, you will need to replace this with your own initialisation code

        board[0][7] = WHITEROOK;
        board[2][7] = WHITEBISHOP;
        board[5][7] = WHITEBISHOP;
        board[7][7] = WHITEROOK;
        board[0][0] = BLACKROOK;
        board[2][0] = BLACKROOK;
        board[5][0] = BLACKROOK;
        board[7][0] = BLACKROOK;


    }


    public void printBoard() {

        // Print the letters at the top
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int x = 0; x < boardsize; x++)
            System.out.print(" " + (char) (x + 'a'));
        System.out.println();

        for (int y = 0; y < boardsize; y++) {
            // Print the numbers on the left side
            System.out.print(8 - y);

            // Print the actual board fields
            for (int x = 0; x < boardsize; x++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                char value = board[x][y];
                if (value == FREE) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                } else if (value >= WHITEKING && value <= BLACKPAWN) {
                    System.out.print(value);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            }
            // Print the numbers on the right side
            System.out.println(" " + (8 - y));
        }

        // Print the letters at the bottom
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int x = 0; x < boardsize; x++)
            System.out.print(" " + (char) (x + 'a'));
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }



    public int getStartingPiecesEach() {
        return (startingPiecesEach);
    }

   public char getChar(int x, int y){
        return(board[x][y]);


   }




    public boolean legalPieceMove(char[][] gameBoard,int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY, Piece piece) {

        char pieceType = piece.getPieceType(gameBoard, fromX, fromY);
        if (pieceType == WHITEROOK) {
            Rook rook = new Rook("white");
            return (rook.moveLegal(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
        } else {
            if (pieceType == BLACKROOK) {
                Rook rook = new Rook("black");
                return (rook.moveLegal(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
            } else {
                if (pieceType == WHITEBISHOP) {
                    Bishop bishop = new Bishop("white");
                    return (bishop.moveLegal(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
                } else {
                    if (pieceType == BLACKBISHOP) {
                        Bishop bishop = new Bishop("black");
                        return (bishop.moveLegal(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
                    } else {
                        return false;

                    }


                }


            }
        }
    }
    public boolean canMovePiece(char[][] gameBoard,int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY, Piece piece, Player player) {
        if (legalPieceMove(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, piece) && piece.correctPlayer(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, player)) {

            return true;
        } else
            {
            return false;
        }
    }





    public void movePiece(char[][] gameBoard,int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY, Player player, Piece piece) {
        if (gameBoard[toX][toY] != FREE) {
            removePiece(gameBoard, fromX, fromY, toX, toY, player, piece);



        }
        else { gameBoard[fromX][fromY]=FREE;
            gameBoard[toX][toY]=piece.getPieceType(gameBoard,fromX,fromY);
            moveNumber++;
        }
    }

//can possibly merge these to one for efficiency



    public void removePiece(char[][] gameBoard,int fromX,int fromY, int toX, int toY, Player player, Piece piece) {
        gameBoard[fromX][fromY] = FREE;
        gameBoard[toX][toY] = piece.getPieceType(gameBoard, fromX, fromY);
        player.addNumberPiecesCaptured();
        moveNumber++;

    }






    public boolean canFindPiece(char[][] gameBoard, int fromX, int fromY) {     //checks that the player has selected a piece

        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard.length; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == gameBoard[fromX][fromY]) {      //checks the user input co-ordinate  is on the board
                    //break was here?      //checks the piece is real, ie not a free space
                    if (gameBoard[fromX][fromY] != FREE) {

                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;

                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

piece....

```
public class Piece {


    private static final char WHITEROOK = '♖';
    private static final char BLACKROOK = '♜';
    private static final char WHITEBISHOP = '♗';
    private static final char BLACKBISHOP = '♝';
    public static final char FREE = '.';
    public String colour;


    public char getPieceType(char[][] gameBoard, int x, int y) {     //method only used when space is not free
        if (gameBoard[x][y] == WHITEROOK) {
            return (WHITEROOK);
        } else {
            if (gameBoard[x][y] == BLACKROOK) {
                return (BLACKROOK);
            } else {
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == WHITEBISHOP) {
                    return (WHITEBISHOP);
                } else {
                    if (gameBoard[x][y] == BLACKBISHOP) {
                        return (BLACKBISHOP);
                    } else return (FREE);

                }

            }
        }
    }


    public int getPieceColour(char[][] gameBoard, int x, int y) {//white indicated by 1s, black indicated by 2s, free spaces by 0
        getPieceType(gameBoard, x, y);
        if (gameBoard[x][y] == WHITEROOK) {
            return (1);
        } else {
            if (gameBoard[x][y] == BLACKROOK) {
                return (2);
            } else {
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == WHITEBISHOP) {
                    return (1);
                } else {
                    if (gameBoard[x][y] == BLACKBISHOP) {
                        return (2);
                    } else {

                        return (0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean correctPlayer(char[][] gameBoard, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY, Player player) {

        if ((player.colour.equals("black") && getPieceColour(gameBoard, fromX, fromY) == 2) || (player.colour.equals("white") && getPieceColour(gameBoard, fromX, fromY) == 1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

example of rook...

```
public class Rook extends Piece {


public Rook(String colour) {
    this.colour= colour;
}





    public ArrayList<int[]> possibleMoves = new ArrayList<int[]>();


    public ArrayList<int[]> generatePossibleMoves(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom) {
        for (int i = 1; xFrom + i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom + i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {//cannot go from free space to free
                if (gameBoard[xFrom + i][yFrom] != FREE) {
                    int[] move = {xFrom + i, yFrom};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                    break;                              //stops iterating here since a rook is not allowed to jump over other pieces
                } else
                    {
                    int[] move = {xFrom + i, yFrom};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; xFrom - i >=0; i++) {
            if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom - i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
                if (gameBoard[xFrom - i][yFrom] != FREE) {
                    int[] move = {xFrom - i, yFrom};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    {
                    int[] move = {xFrom - i, yFrom};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; yFrom + i < gameBoard.length; i++) {       //makes sure the place to be moved is on the board
            if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom , yFrom+ i) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
                if (gameBoard[xFrom][yFrom+i] != FREE) {
                    int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom+i};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    {
                    int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom+i};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; yFrom- i >=0; i++)
            if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom - i) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
                if (gameBoard[xFrom][yFrom - i] != FREE) {
                    int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom - i};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                    break;
                } else {
                    int[] move = {xFrom, yFrom - i};
                    possibleMoves.add(move);
                }
            }
        return possibleMoves;
    }




    public boolean moveLegal(char[][] gameBoard, int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo){
            int wantedMove[] = {xTo, yTo};                                          //created wantedMove variable so that it could be checked if it is in the possibleMoves
            possibleMoves= generatePossibleMoves(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom);    //problem
            if (possibleMoves.contains(wantedMove)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: and why are you not running the program with a debugger step by step? Any IDE provides this, you can see current values of variables etc.

Comment: how do you do this on intellij?

Comment: You can do this so: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/breakpoints.html

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to this, no one can see an issue thats glaringly obvious?

Comment: It's much faster if you run the code and use the debugger. Just set a breakpoint at the beginning of the main method, then start the program with "debug as Java application". Then use F3 and F5 to navigate through the execution of the code. It's really simple

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in the code but this will help to solve your error. You asked in the post how to debug and I will try to show you how to rearrange the code:

This snipped is exactly the same:

```
 String Player1Pos1 = reader.getString();         //gets user input ... move from... to....   temporary variables
            int x1From = Player1Pos1.charAt(0) - 'a';                           //to transform the letter      ASCII values
            int y1From = 8 - (Player1Pos1.charAt(1) - '1') - 1;                           // to transform the number
```

Why not use a separate function:

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> getPlayerPosition(String x, String y)
```

In the function legalPieceMove(...) you have a lot of duplicate code. I think you do not need the difference between white and black. The function is then really short. With a switch statment or "if" "else if" "else" statement the code is more readable.

In the Board class nearly every function needs the board variable. Why you do not use the instance variable instead. Then your function parameter-list is a little bit shorter.

I am not able to modify your code because I do not have the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
for (...) {
    if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom - i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

You have to leave the for-loop if getPieceColour(...) == getPieceColour(...):

```
for (...) {
    if (getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom - i, yFrom) != getPieceColour(gameBoard, xFrom, yFrom)) {
       ...
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```